# how to get values of map in cypher

Tags: neo4j, maps, cypher

Starting from a map `map` in cypher, I can get the keys via `keys(map)`, but it seems there is no `values` analogon, also APOC doesn't seem to have a suitable procedure.

**edit:**
using newest neo4j and apoc versions

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [List Comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/syntax/lists/#cypher-list-comprehension) syntax can produce a list of map values fairly succinctly:

```
[k IN KEYS(map) | map[k]]
```

Comment: alright thank you, I feel it won't get anymore concise than that

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround, you can use this solution using [reduce()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-reduce) and [keys()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-keys) functions:

```
match(node)
with reduce(values = [], key in keys(node) | values + node[key]) as values
return values
```

Comment: I guess that's fine, yet it gets really messy in my usecase - I need to modify the keys in a map slightly. can it be improved in any way for that special case?

Comment: @tscherg what you mean with "modify the keys in a map"?

Comment: @tscherg and what you think about `match(a) 
return apoc.map.values(a, keys(a))`?

Comment: `apoc.map.values` does not seem to exist in´the current apoc version

Comment: @tscherg what APOC version are you using?